# error in query with JOIN USING

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-error-1142

Consider this simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 USING(pid) WHERE pid='2' ;
```

I get this error:

> 1142: SELECT command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for column 'pid' in table 'table1'

When I replace `USING` with `ON` (and this right syntax...) the error disappears.

What is the problem?

Comment: Are you running these commands from the CLI client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is saying that your database security is setup to not allow the user context being run under doesn't have access to that column. What permissions have been applied to that column?

Try to fix those permissions problems. Grant select permissions, or remove those deny permissions.

Comment: yes,both of them have the pid column.
but USING works before... ;(